# Destination Folder Access Denied - You need permission to perform this action

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, windows-server-2012-r2, mapped-drive

I am trying to write files to a mapped network drive (from one server to another).

I am trying to write as a user 'opcon' on our 'opcon' server to a mapped drive that is on our image server, and which it seems 'opcon' has permissions for, but I am having no success. Anybody know what i need to do?

Both the Opcon and Image servers are Windows Server 2012 R2

Properties says that opcon has Full Control:

[image: Properties says that opcon has Full Control]

But when I try and right-click create new file in that directory:

[image: But when I try and right-click create new file in that directory]

Net use results with a space:

[image: Net use results with a space]

Net use results without a space

[[image: Net use results without a space]][5]

Comment: There are share permissions and NTFS file permissions.  They are separate things.  Check them from the server side if you can.

Comment: Open  cmd.exe on the first server. Then NET USE T: \\secondserver\folder and authenticate. What numerical Windows error do you get?

Comment: With what is probably the wrong path - a 67. Then I put a space after the colon and got 85

Comment: You don’t show who owns the folder or the permission inheritance

Comment: From an Internet search on Error 85 "System error 85 happens when a user attempts to map a particular resource to a network drive. To put it simply, this error is caused by a user attempting to use a network drive letter that is already in use by another network drive."  See if changing the user name helps. You were using the same name

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I somehow managed to get logged out and logged in again as my already existing Stack Exchange account

but Senor CMasMas tip about NFTS vs Sharing helped me figure this out

I followed https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/05/03/differences-between-share-and-ntfs-permissions/  and changed Sharing Permissions

Comment: You should specify within the answer, what you did exactly, instead of entirely relying on the external link