# Destination Folder Access Denied - You need permission to perform this action (Despite having Security/ Sharing Privileges)

Tags: permissions, filesystems, ntfs, sharing

I actually asked about this issue a few days ago and thought I found the answer, even linked the site that showed my 'solution' (before trying the solution) but when I tried it (giving my 'Opcon' user Sharing permissions in addition to the NTFS permissions on a folder in the image server) Opcon still did not have the ability to write there. I get **Destination Folder Access Denied - You need permission to perform this action.** Anybody know what the issue is, if I seem to have Security and Sharing rights?

Basically tried solution here (part about giving Sharing permissions):

https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/05/03/differences-between-share-and-ntfs-permissions/

But now I get this message on writes:
[image]

[image: Security]

[image: Sharing]
Original Ticket:

[Destination Folder Access Denied - You need permission to perform this action](https://superuser.com/questions/1514484/destination-folder-access-denied-you-need-permission-to-perform-this-action/1514507#1514507)

Comment: What is the numerical NET USE error that you get?

Comment: So when I do NET USE T: \sharedpath\ I get 85 'The local device name is already in use' . If I just do net use \sharedpath\ I get Status ok, with 2 Opens and 2 Connections. i do not know what this all means, but I put the T there as someone told me to do that in my last ticket

Comment: System error 85 happens when a user attempts to map a particular resource to a network drive. To put it simply, this error is caused by a user attempting to use a network drive letter that is already in use by another network drive.  Check this

Comment: Ok, well that \sharedpath\ is mapped to G:    If I do net use G: I get Status Ok, just as if I do net use \sharedpath\. I do not know why someone else asked me to put the T in there. Is it a problem that this filepath is mapped to G: ? I get to the path in explorer by clicking on that G: shared folder, and I can read from that with my python script by specifying G: (just cannot write)

Comment: If the sharename is **CRIFLoans** why are you not using **\\00-it-img-02\CRIFLoans** as the unc path? Otherwise you're being restricted by the share permissions for the share called '**C**'. You either need to map direct to '*\\00-it-img-02\CRIFLoans*' or set the permissions on the share called '*C*'. I would also advise using the **Shared Folders** MMC Snap-in rather than the simple right click share menu.

Comment: Ok, so when I put \\00-IT-IMG-02\CRIFLoans in explorer (on my opcon server) and then try and create a new file, no more permission errors. I will use that path in my python script as well and I think it will work. Thank you guys for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a path \SERVER\C\TOSHAREDPATH

Instead of \SERVER\SHAREDPATH

And this was why I had permission errors, it was looking to share permissions on 'C'